# Pipe Number cause karma to crash

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

Using Pipe Number case karma to fail load component

When I remove the pipe the test pass

However in the app everything works fine

Here is how i use pipe in my template

```
{{ facture | number:'0.2':'fr' }}
```

or

```
{{ facture | currency:'EUR':'symbol':'0.2-2':'fr' }}
```

If I put every test passes except that I don't get the proper formatting

```
 {{ facture }}
```

Here is my test config

```
import { CurrencyPipe, DecimalPipe, PercentPipe } from '@angular/common';


fdescribe('MontantFacturesComponent', () => {
  const contentTitle: String = 'Choisissez les factures à payer' ;
  const facturesUpdate: String = '30 Octobre 2018 à 18:52:48' ;
  const factureTotal: String = '232,40' ;

  let component: MontantFacturesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MontantFacturesComponent>;
  let componentEL: DebugElement ;

  let contentTitleEL: DebugElement ;
  let nomClient: DebugElement ;
  let numClient: DebugElement ;

  let factureHead: DebugElement ;
  let factureBody: DebugElement ;
  let factureFoot: DebugElement ;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const comp = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        AngularFontAwesomeModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(<Routes>[]), 
        HttpClientModule, 
      ],
      declarations: [ 
        MontantFacturesComponent,
      ],
      providers : [
        AppService,
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' },
        CommonModule,
        CurrencyPipe, DecimalPipe, PercentPipe
      ]
    }) ;

    // Configure the component with another set of Providers
    TestBed.overrideComponent(
        MontantFacturesComponent,
        {set: {providers: [{provide: AppService, useClass: MockAppService}]}}
    );
    comp.compileComponents();
  }));
```

With or without providers for pipe and `commonModule` nothing change

```
        CommonModule,
        CurrencyPipe, DecimalPipe, PercentPipe
```

It looks like my whole component goes undefined when I have the pipe in my template

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'CommonModule' declared by the module

 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

Looks like the problem is the use of local `fr`

both

```
{{factureTotal | currency:'EUR':'symbol':'0.2-2':'fr'}}
```

and

```
{{factureTotal | currency:'EUR':'symbol':'0.2-2':'fr-FR'}}
```

Fails but

```
{{factureTotal | currency:'EUR':'symbol':'0.2-2'}}
```

Is fine any idea how to make karma work

Comment: Why have you put `CommonModule` in the *`providers`?!*

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just trying a few thing i found on the net

Comment: It's a *module*, it should be in `imports` - where did you find that?

Comment: Find the answer to this problem however i posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49283657/revisions where i asking for how to mock a pipe

Comment: I know, I've both commented on it and edited it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem after a week of looking

It looks like karma is not loading locals format

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
registerLocaleData(localeFr);
```

this solves the problem that was causing the testComponent to crash